# Mule exception: A required object/property muleContext is null

Tags: mule

I get the above error when fetching values from database. What is value of the muleContext if I want to set it?Below is my config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:x12-edi="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/x12-edi" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/x12-edi http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/x12-edi/current/mule-x12-edi.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd">
<x12-edi:config name="X12_EDI_files" doc:name="X12 EDI">
<x12-edi:schemas>
<x12-edi:schema>/x12/005010/850.esl</x12-edi:schema>
</x12-edi:schemas>
</x12-edi:config>
<context:property-placeholder location="DBConnection.properties"/>
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration_Insert" host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}" user="${db.username}" password="${db.password}" database="${db.database}" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
<flow name="edi_retailFlow">
<file:inbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources/input" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]_archive.edi" moveToDirectory="src/main/resources/output" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Read File"/>
<x12-edi:read config-ref="X12_EDI_files" doc:name="Reads X12 EDI message"/>
<enricher target="#[flowVars.batchResult]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
<choice doc:name="Choice">
<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename contains 810]">
<batch:execute name="Process_810_Batch" doc:name="Process_810_Batch"/>
</when>
<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename contains 850]">
<batch:execute name="Process_850_Batch" doc:name="Process_850_Batch"/>
</when>
</choice>
</enricher>
<flow-ref name="Send_Ack" doc:name="Send_Ack"/>
</flow>
<flow name="Send_Ack">
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform 997 Ack">
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
TransactionSets: {
v005010: {
"997": payload.FunctionalAcksGenerated
}
}
}]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
<x12-edi:write config-ref="X12_EDI_files" doc:name="X12 EDI">
<x12-edi:map ref="#[payload]"/>
</x12-edi:write>
<file:outbound-endpoint path="src/main/resources/output" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]_997.edi" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
<batch:job name="Process_850_Batch">
<batch:input>
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="973d0231-b863-428a-8414-eb6a2d69b15b" doc:name="Process 850">
<dw:input-payload mimeType="application/java"/>
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.TransactionSets.v005010."850"]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
</batch:input>
<batch:process-records>
<batch:step name="Batch_Step">
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="e7c299fd-8246-4cca-9466-9f81db4a8498" doc:name="Object to Json">
<dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\map_2.dwl"/>
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
purchaseOrder: {
purchaseOrderNumber: payload.Heading."0200_BEG".BEG03,
transactionCode: payload.Heading."0200_BEG".BEG01,
transactionTypeCode: payload.Heading."0200_BEG".BEG02,
dateTime: payload.Heading."0200_BEG".BEG05 as :string,
currency: payload.Heading."0400_CUR".CUR02,
buyerDetailspayload.Heading."3100_N1_Loop" map ((v3100Loop,indexOfv3100Loop) -> {
billToName: v3100Loop."3100_N1".N102,
(btn_contact: v3100Loop."3600_PER"[0].PER04) when v3100Loop."3600_PER"[0].PER03=='TE',
btn_address: v3100Loop."3300_N3"[0].N301
} when v3100Loop."3100_N1".N101 =='BT' otherwise '')),
shipperDetailspayload.Heading."3100_N1_Loop" map ((v3100Loop,indexOfv3100Loop) -> {
shipToName: v3100Loop."3100_N1".N102,
(stn_contact: v3100Loop."3600_PER"[0].PER04) when v3100Loop."3600_PER"[0].PER03=='TE',
stn_address: v3100Loop."3300_N3"[0].N301
} when v3100Loop."3100_N1".N101 =='ST' otherwise '')),
productDetails: (payload.Detail."0100_PO1_Loop" map ((v0100Loop, indexOfv0100Loop) -> {
productName: v0100Loop."0500_PID_Loop"[0]."0500_PID".PID05, 
quantity: v0100Loop."0100_PO1".PO102,
price: v0100Loop."0100_PO1".PO104 as :string
}))
}
}]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="69ab44ca-d9c5-4436-9093-77fca72a7dd7" doc:name="Trim Null">
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
purchaseOrder: {
purchaseOrderNumber: payload.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderNumber,
transactionCode: payload.purchaseOrder.transactionCode,
transactionTypeCode: payload.purchaseOrder.transactionTypeCode,
dateTime: payload.purchaseOrder.dateTime,
currency: payload.purchaseOrder.currency,
(buyerDetails: {
billToName: payload.purchaseOrder.buyerDetails.billToName,
btn_contact: payload.purchaseOrder.buyerDetails.btn_contact,
btn_address: payload.purchaseOrder.buyerDetails.btn_address
}) when payload.purchaseOrder.buyerDetails.billToName !='',
(shipperDetails: {
shipToName: payload.purchaseOrder.shipperDetails.shipToName,
stn_contact: payload.purchaseOrder.shipperDetails.stn_contact,
stn_address: payload.purchaseOrder.shipperDetails.stn_address
}) when payload.purchaseOrder.shipperDetails.shipToName !='',
productDetailspayload.purchaseOrder.productDetails map ((vprod, indexOfvprod) -> {
productName: vprod.productName,
quantity: vprod.quantity,
price: vprod.price
}))
}
}]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
<logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Json to Object">
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
<set-variable variableName="InputPayload" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration_Insert" doc:name="Insert in Buyer_Table">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into Buyer_Table (billtoname, btn_contact, btn_address, shiptoname, stn_contact, stn_address) values (#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.buyerDetails.billToName], #[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.buyerDetails.btn_contact],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.buyerDetails.btn_address],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.shipperDetails.shipToName],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.shipperDetails.stn_contact], #[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.shipperDetails.stn_address]);]]></db:parameterized-query>

</db:insert>
<db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration_Insert" doc:name="Get buyer_id">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT buyer_id FROM Buyer_Table WHERE buyer_id = (SELECT MAbuyer_id) FROM Buyer_Table);]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>
<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration_Insert" doc:name="Insert in PO_Table">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into PO_Table (buyer_id,purchaseorder_no,transaction_type,transaction_code,date_time,currency) 
values (#[payload[0].buyer_id],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderNumber], #[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.transactionTypeCode],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.transactionCode],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.dateTime],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.currency]);]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:insert>
<db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration_Insert" doc:name="Get po_no">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT po_no FROM PO_Table WHERE po_no = (SELECT MApo_no) FROM PO_Table);]]></db:parameterized-query>
</db:select>

<db:insert config-ref="MySQL_Configuration_Insert" bulkMode="true" doc:name="Insert in Product_Table">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into Product_Table (po_no,product_name,quantity,unit_price) values (#[payload[0].po_no],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.productDetails.productName],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.productDetails.quantity],#[flowVars.InputPayload.purchaseOrder.productDetails.price]);]]></db:parameterized-query>

</db:insert>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:step>
</batch:process-records>
<batch:on-complete>
<logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
<batch:job name="Process_810_Batch">
<batch:input>
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="6d57575e-bbca-46ca-88f8-565f438dcf79" doc:name="Transform Message">
<dw:input-payload mimeType="application/java"/>
<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload.TransactionSets.v005010."810"]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
</batch:input>
<batch:process-records>
<batch:step name="Batch_Step1">
<logger message="&quot;In 810&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:step>
</batch:process-records>
<batch:on-complete>
<logger message="&quot;Batch 810 complete&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
</mule>
```

I thought the muleContext is automatically passed but for this error, How to set muleContext property?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have this error? I have different for your xml file. It is, actually, syntax error. And I do not see any place where you try to use muleContext in provided source:

[image]

Comment: I had removed queries in the code. Can you check now? Thanks

Comment: Ok but how to set muleContext?

Comment: You are absolutely right - muleContext is used inside Mule objects and you should not worry about it at all. Only when you use some external (Java, Groovy, Python) components you should obtain it (again, automatically). Since there is no such stuff in your code - it's impossible to know where error is. In process of creating SSCCE you will pinpoint the location of your error and, I'm almost sure, you will see the error by yourself. If not - we can help you. So far I found you your first error. Keep digging. Remove all unnecessary pieces  (like DB stuff) one by one and error will disappear.